What is this brass plumbing device on my pex supply line?
This morning, my garden tub sprung a leak at a failed compression fitting. In the process of figuring out what I need to fix it, I found this device. What is it, and do I actually need it? Could it be a code requirement?
The arrow shows the failure, the circled device is what I'm wondering if I need. I'd prefer to cap the cold inlet to the device and use an PEX extender to replace the 'T'.


Not the best picture for identifying it unambiguously, but it matches the expected parameters for a temperature regulating (anti-scald) valve; so deleting the cold input would likely result in a code violation. The beige dial pointing towards the floor should be the temperature setting. A picture a bit closer in and showing where all the connections go would reduce the ambiguity, but that's very likely what it is.
Why it is has to do with a very common source of first and second degree burns in the home. Children, old folks and others with reduced mobility are most commonly affected.
